# Can´t start the Suricata service

Tags: windows, powershell, suricata

I installed Suricata but can´t actually start it.
How can i do it?

When i try to start it a error shows up saying:

The Suricata service on local computer was started and stopped. Some services are stopped automatically if they are not being used by other services or programs

Comment: Check the log files in the `log` directory in the folder where Suricata was installed. Can you point us to the installer you used? Last I checked, Suricata didn't provide a Windows Service wrapper

Comment: The suricata logs where created and when i test suricata the logs are being registred but i still can´t start it neither in the windows services or by powershell. I installed Suricata 6.0.5

Comment: ok i wen't into a virtual machine to test it following the same steps that i did in my own pc and it worked